# PHP Group associative Array duplicates and make subarrays of different values

Tags: performance, php, array

I have this type of table:

```php
$this->data = [
  0 => [
    'reference' => 'ABC123',
    'title' => 'lorem',
    'parent' => 12,
  ],
  1 => [
    'reference' => 'ABC456',
    'title' => 'ipsum',
    'parent' => 42,
  ],
  2 => [
    'reference' => 'ABC789',
    'title' => 'dolor',
    'parent' => 36,
  ],
  3 => [
    'reference' => 'ABC123',
    'title' => 'lorem',
    'parent' => 18,
  ],
  4 => [
    'reference' => 'ABC789',
    'title' => 'dolor',
    'parent' => 26,
  ]
];
```

And I made this script to remove duplicates with keeping different known keys as subarrays:

```php
// Get number of duplicates for each 'reference' of $this->data
$occurences = array_count_values(array_column($this->data, 'reference'));

// Array to put index to remove of $this->data
$to_unset = [];
foreach($occurences as $reference => $count) {
  // If item unique, continue
  if($count == 1) continue;

  // Get all indexes of 'reference' inside $this->data
  $indexes = array_keys(array_column($this->data, 'reference'), $reference);

  // Keep first index of occurence
  $first_index = $indexes[0];
    // Remove it from indexes
    unset($indexes[0]);

  // Keep the first occurence
  $model = $this->data[$first_index];
    // Convert different known keys as array
    $model['parent'] = [$model['parent']];
      
  foreach($indexes as $index){
    // Group 'parent' in same array
    array_push($model['parent'], $this->data[$index]['parent']);
      
    // Put index to remove then
    array_push($to_unset, $index);
  }

  // Replace the first item occurence by model
  $this->data[$first_index] = $model;
}

// Remove all occurences
$this->data = array_diff_key($this->data, array_flip($to_unset));

// Reindex
$this->data = array_values($this->data);
```

To get this:

```php
$array = [
  0 => [
    'reference' => 'ABC123',
    'title' => 'lorem',
    'parent' => [12, 18],
  ],
  1 => [
    'reference' => 'ABC456',
    'title' => 'ipsum',
    'parent' => 42,
  ],
  2 => [
    'reference' => 'ABC789',
    'title' => 'dolor',
    'parent' => [36, 26],
  ]
];
```

But my script is very slow (20 seconds for +13k items), how can I improve it ?

Comment: For a given reference, if present multiple times, can it have different titles?

Comment: What I need is to remove the duplicate data by grouping by the key "reference" and grouping the possible different values ​​in subarrays ;-)

Comment: Same basic technique as https://stackoverflow.com/a/68885107/2943403  (don't mind the revenge vote on my answer -- it's Stack Overflow)

Comment: @Aur what is the source of this input data? Perhaps it can be restructured in an earlier layer.  Or maybe I should ask _why_ you are doing this.  Is this an XY Problem? Why do you need all 13000 rows of data?

Comment: @mickmackusa This input data comes from a data interface which unfortunately I cannot optimize further

Answer (score 2):

### Broad review

It seems this code is part of a class method, yet it is difficult to know anything about the method or class other than the fact that it has a `data` member.

Consider following [PSR-1](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) and [PSR-12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/).

Indentation is not always consistent - e.g. some lines are indented with two spaces and others appear to have four spaces yet at the same indentation level. For example:

> ```
>   // Keep the first occurence
>   $model = $this->data[$first_index];
>     // Convert different known keys as array
>     $model['parent'] = [$model['parent']];
> ```

From PSR-12 Section 2. General:

> #### 2.4 Indenting
>
> Code MUST use an indent of 4 spaces for each indent level, and MUST NOT use tabs for indenting.

---

There is a loose equality comparison at the start of the loop:

> ```
> if($count == 1) continue;
> ```

Since both operands in the condition should be integers strict equality comparison (i.e. `===`) can be used. [It is a good habit to use strict equality operators](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/126585/244085) whenever possible.

### Possible optimizations

My initial suggestion was going to be to make a new array with the *reference* values as the keys and have the values be arrays from the *parent* values of the original data, however that may likely require a lot more memory than is acceptable.

If memory allows, it could be simplified like this:

```
$trimmedData = [];
foreach ($this->data as $model) {
    // reference already exists in final array
    if (isset($trimmedData[$model['reference']])) {
        $target = &$trimmedData[$model['reference']];
        // ensure parent list is an array
        if (!is_array($target['parent'])) {
            $target['parent'] = [$target['parent']];
        }
        $target['parent'][] = $model['parent'];
    } else {
        //set the index using the reference value
        $trimmedData[$model['reference']] = $model;
    }
}
// reindex, remove index by reference
$this->data = array_values($trimmedData);
```

---

I noticed that there is a call to `array_column($this->data, 'reference')` on two lines:

> ```
> $occurences = array_count_values(array_column($this->data, 'reference'));
> ```

as well as this line within the `foreach` loop:

> ```
> $indexes = array_keys(array_column($this->data, 'reference'), $reference);
> ```

For the sample data those inner calls to get the values in the `reference` column yield the same value - that could be stored in a variable before the loop and used in those two lines, which would eliminate the call on each iteration of the loop where the count of that value occurs more than once.

---

Instead of storing `$first_index` and then calling `unset` on that index, you could consider doing that in one line using [`array_splice()`](https://php.net/array_splice) though I'm not sure if performance would be better or worse.

Instead of:

> ```
> // Keep first index of occurence
> $first_index = $indexes[0];
> // Remove it from indexes
> unset($indexes[0]);
> ```

use `array_splice()`:

```
$first_index = array_splice($indexes, 0, 1)[0];
```

Comment: Thanks ! array_reduce method is better, but still too long (~19 seconds now)

Comment: In hindsight I should have mentioned using `array_reduce()` would most likely be slower because it is executing an additional function for each iteration - perhaps that wasn't worth mentioning